# Creating .vcf file and save it into mobile contacts

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

creating `.vcf` files fore all customers stored in DB so that we can push it to mobile contacts I was able to create `.vcf` file wondering how can i save this files to mobile contact automatically . if i save `.vcf` file to SD card once again it asks me to save it in contacts

but i need to save contacts directly

Can i save this to Google and can i sync from there 
below is the code what i have done

```
import java.io.*;

public class Vcard{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

      File f=new File("D:\\contact.vcf");
      FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(f);

      if(f.exists()){
      String str="BEGIN:VCARD\n" +
                 "VERSION:4.0\n" +
                 "N:Gump;Forrest;;;\n" +
                 "FN:Forrest Gump\n"+
                 "ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.\n"+
                 "TITLE:Shrimp Man\n"+
                 "TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212\n"+
                    "EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com\n"+

                 "END:VCARD";
          fop.write(str.getBytes());
          //Now read the content of the vCard after writing data into it
          BufferedReader br = null;
          String sCurrentLine;
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("contact.vcf"));
          while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
   }
          //close the output stream and buffer reader
          fop.flush();
          fop.close();
          System.out.println("The data has been written");
          }

          else
            System.out.println("This file does not exist");
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated